# Formula to pull MySQL data

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I have data in MySQL that I'm trying to pull directly into a CELL in an Excel worksheet pursuant to parameters that I'll set out. I'm aware of how to import a complete MySQL table etc etc, however am not looking for that here. I can see VBA approaches however am keen to see whether this can be done without using VBA.

The aim of what I'm doing is to ultimately make the cell formula dynamic by linking to other cells containing parameters - change those parameters, the cell calls MySQL and returns updated data.

Comment: If you are 'keen to see whether this can be done without using VBA' then why the [vba] and [excel-vba] tags?

Comment: What you would like is called a **UDF** and it can be done quite readily in VBA. This question however is far too broad.